# How to make VLC server that can communicate with clients

Tags: linux, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming

I have VLC 2.0.8 in and I have recently discovered that I can stream movies by using it.

So my plan is:
- at home I have a computer with a list of 3 movies (for example).
- when I am traveling, I connect to VLC via HTTP and use the Video Over Demand Feature (VoD, http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch05.html) to see a movie in my laptop.

However, I have no idea on how to actually do this. I have read the documentation, and this is what I understood:
- I have to enable VLC to be streamed via HTTP and configure it to be a VLC server (on my desktop back at Home). I also have to leave VLC and the computer open and running xD
- I can only communicate with the client via UDP

I have read the documentation to make VLC a streaming server, but I have failed miserably. I am not even going to talk about the client.
I am using Linux Mint, but I assume this is OS independent.

How to I configure VLC to do this? Can any of you guys land a hand to a newbie like me? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are other products out there that make this very easy.  I would suggest checking out [Plex](https://plex.tv/) before going down this route, but if you want to do it with VLC, here is how I would do it:

1. Setup the VLM Configuration

   1. Run the VLC GUI
   2. Select Tools -> VLM Configuration tool
   3. Use this tool to setup the videos you want to stream. For each video
   4. Select "Video On Demand" from the first dropdown
   5. Select a name for the media (don't use spaces)
   6. Select the video file as the input
   7. Leave the output and muxer blank.
   8. Select "Add"
   9. Repeat 4-8 for each of your media files.
   10. Export the configuration.
2. Setup VLC VOD

   1. Start VLC using the command line: `vlc -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password <your_password> --rtsp-host 0.0.0.0 --rtsp-port 5554`
   2. Connect to the telnet server on port `4212` using the password in the above command line
   3. Once connected, load the configuration file you exported above.  Type the command `load <path_to>/<configuration_file>.vlm`
3. Test the Client

   1. Open an instance of the VLC GUI.
   2. Open a network stream and point it to `rtsp://localhost:5554/<name_of_media>` where `<name_of_media>` is the name of one of the streams you configured in the VLM Configuration GUI.

That should get you started.  You may still need to setup some port forwarding rules from your router to your computer and maybe dynamic DNS to make accessing your computer easy, but that is VLC related configuration you need.

Note: On Windows the telnet interface is broken in VLC 2.1.x

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, I am really interested in some of your points. First, I checked Plex,and it seems that the streaming service they provide is payed, at least according to the website.
As for the telnet thing, I installed telnetd on my Linux, but when I do `telnet localhost:4212` I get a `telnet: could not resolve localhost:4212/telnet: System error` error and I dont know why. If I try `telnet localhost` then I am prompted to enter a username and password, but no matter what I do, the login is always incorrect. Can you help me (again?)Also, what are the alternatives (besides plex?)

Comment: As far as Plex is concerned accessing media on mobile devices requires a paid app, but you can access the web interface remotely for free [See Here](https://plexapp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484543-Connecting-a-Server).  As for VLC, you don't need to install telnetd, just the telnet client (which it looks like you have already).  The syntax for the telnet client is:  `telent <host> <port>` so try `telnet localhost 4212`.

Comment: Well, in the client when I do "rtsp://localhost:5554/Name" I still get an error. I have to agree that VLC is quite terrible for this. But I am now trying Plex and it sure looks promising. Thanks !

Comment: I just tried going through the steps on a Linux system.  I rad into one little problem, so I've updated the vlc command line with a new parameter `--rtsp-port 5554` instead of specifying it with the bind address.